# Вывод последнего значения из БД.

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Здравствуйте.
В таблице есть поле date, формат: `'2016-05-26 15:26:27'` как вывести последнее значение даты из таблицы? 
Пробовал делать так:

```
" SELECT date FROM tab WHERE MAX(date) = date"
" SELECT date FROM tab ORDER BY MAX(date)"
" SELECT date FROM tab ORDER BY date"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT date FROM tab ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Выводит **не последнюю** дату.

Comment: @Макс враньё...

Comment: цитата: враньё...  Вы судите по себе? Вывело не последнее значение даты.

Comment: @Макс значит **ВЫ** делаете что-то не то ... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19a730/1

Comment: вы правы, неубрал  **MAX(date)** `SELECT MAX(date), date FROM test ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1`.   А если таблица очень большая, насколько производительно данное решение?

Comment: Если нет индекса на поле даты, о производительности можно только тихо плакать.

Comment: @Алексей, 1. Вы имеете ввиду индекса в строке, или ряду.  2. Если индекс не используется в данном случае при сортировке, как это влияет на производительность?

Comment: @Макс я ничего не имел в виду.... вы смотрите с кем беседу ведете. 1) что такое индекс индекс по строке или по ряду? 2) без индекса ясен пень будет хуже работать. Однако без индекса и `MAX(date)` просядет.

Comment: @Алексей. Не посмотрел, вели обсуждение с вами, а ответил другой :). 1. цитата: что такое индекс индекс по строке или по ряду? Akina сказал: Если нет индекса на поле даты.  уточнил: возможно имеется ввиду ряды, а не поля.

Answer (score 3):

Или

```
SELECT MAX(date) FROM tab;
```

Для вывода всей записи (если date уникально)

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab 
WHERE date IN (
               SELECT MAX(date) 
               FROM tab
              );
-- вместо IN можно использовать использовать = ANY либо = SOME
```

или

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tab t1, (SELECT MAX(t2.date) date FROM tab t2) t3
WHERE t1.date = t3.date
```

Comment: Работает пример: `SELECT date FROM tab ORDER BY date DESC`  Ваш пример нет.

Comment: @Макс *SELECT date FROM tab ORDER BY date DESC* в принципе не может работать так, как требуется, т.к. возвращает все записи, а нужна одна. Насчёт моего кода - < http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19a730/3/0 > полагает, что он работает, причём как нужно, возвращая одну запись, причём с максимальным значением даты.

Comment: цитата: `SELECT date FROM tab ORDER BY date DESC` *в принципе не может работать так, как требуется*,    я вывозу без цыкла, и у меня выводится последнее значение, вы говорите о производительности? и что обязательно нужно добавить `

SELECT date FROM tab ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1`  Вот код он выводит не коректно: **pole** `SELECT date, pole FROM tab ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Вот код он выводит не коректно: **pole** `SELECT MAX(date), pole FROM tab;`

Comment: В исходном вопросе про поле речь не шла - не надо менять условие "на ходу". Но если нужна вся запись - используйте приведённый код в качестве подзапроса в условии отбора (как я понимаю, значения в поле date уникальны).

Comment: Да уникальны, можно пример.  По поводу: `SELECT date FROM tab ORDER BY date DESC`. Что вы имели ввиду? Ухудшение производительности без `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: По поводу - я имел в виду, что в исходном вопросе надо "вывести последнее значение даты из таблицы" - которое по определению ОДНО. А этот запрос без LIMIT 1 выведет ВСЕ - т.е. если в таблице более одной записи, задача решена не будет.

Comment: [Пример решения работает.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e80018/1).  Можно ваш пример решения задачи с подзапросом? И какой вариант решения эффективнее, и почему?

Comment: Вывожу без цыкла, поэтому LIMIT 1 ненужен.

Comment: Ваш пример `SELECT * FROM tab WHERE date IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tab);` на большой таблице долго выполняется.

Comment: Ну как бы нужен индекс по полю date, тогда взлетит. А иначе это double fullscan. Впрочем, на очень большой таблице он всё равно может быть выгоднее, чем filesort. И - запрос с подзапросом в секции FROM предпочтительнее, чем в секции WHERE. Имхо.

Comment: Индекс на поле data: UNIQUE ?

Comment: Только если логика бизнес-процесса требует уникальности. Иначе обычный индекс.